# How to display CST or CDT after the date & time in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

How to display CST or CDT after the date & time, like shown below.

Sep 09 2022 10:30:32 PM CDT

Thanks.

Comment: Is your column defined as `timestamp` or `timestamp with timezone`?

Comment: It is a DATE column in an Oracle table.  So it does have timestamp.

Comment: I always forget that for Oracle, DATE means date and time.  In any case, it does not support time zone.

Comment: Oh OK.  Thanks for trying me to help.  Most appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the functions sessiontimezone and dbtimezone?

Comment: @oisene I did come across those functions while researching this.  How do I use these functions to display/determine what to display?  Apologies if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type of `TIMESTAMP '2022-09-09 22:30:32 US/CENTRAL'` and then format it using `TO_CHAR` and the format model `'Mon DD YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM TZD'`:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TIMESTAMP '2022-09-09 22:30:32 US/CENTRAL',
         'Mon DD YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM TZD',
         'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=American'
       ) AS ts
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

| TS |
| --- |
| Sep 09 2022 10:30:32 PM CDT |

---

If you have a `DATE` then cast it to a timestamp and use `FROM_TZ` to give it the `US/CENTRAL` time zone and then convert it to a string as above:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         FROM_TZ(
           CAST(
             DATE '2022-09-09' + INTERVAL '22:30:32' HOUR TO SECOND
             AS TIMESTAMP
           ),
           'US/CENTRAL'
         ),
         'Mon DD YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM TZD',
         'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=American'
       ) AS ts
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which also outputs:

| TS |
| --- |
| Sep 09 2022 10:30:32 PM CDT |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9WwrANdu)

Comment: Perfect!! This is exactly what I am looking for. To understand, why did you add INTERVAL '22:30:32'?

Comment: @maskeerr To get your sample date, I could have used `TO_DATE('2022-09-09 22:30:32', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` or I could have used a date literal and added an interval day to second literal to get the time component. Either works but I chose to do the latter. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tmeZd6eV)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this...

```sql
SELECT 
  To_Char(To_TimeStamp_TZ(To_Char(SYSDATE, 'Mon dd yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'Mon dd yyyy hh24:mi:ss ' || 'TZH:TZM'), 'Mon dd yyyy hh24:mi:ss ') ||
  CASE To_Char(To_TimeStamp_TZ(To_Char(SYSDATE, 'Mon dd yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'Mon dd yyyy hh24:mi:ss ' || 'TZH:TZM'), 'TZH:TZM') 
      WHEN '-05:00' THEN  'CDT'
      WHEN '-06:00' THEN  'CST'
      -- ... ...
      WHEN '+01:00' THEN  'CET'
      WHEN '+02:00' THEN  'EET'
      -- ... ... ...
  ELSE
      To_Char(To_TimeStamp_TZ(To_Char(SYSDATE, 'Mon dd yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'Mon dd yyyy hh24:mi:ss ' || 'TZH:TZM'), 'Mon dd yyyy hh24:mi:ss TZH:TZM')
  END "DTM"
FROM DUAL
```

.... which in my case results as

```sql
--  DTM                       
--  ---------------------------
--  Oct 13 2022 19:19:03 EET
```

... OR if I exclude WHEN '+02:00' from case expresssion (forcing result to ELSE part)

```sql
--  DTM                       
--  ---------------------------
--  Oct 13 2022 19:22:07 +02:00
```

More about To_TimeStamp_TZ() function at: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions194.htm

Time zone definitions at: https://greenwichmeantime.com/time-zone/definition/
Regards...